# How to customize ParseUUIDPipe error messages in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs

I have added validation to make sure that a UUID is actually passed to my NestJS controller with `ParseUUIDPipe` like this

```ts
@Get(':id')
async getItem(
  @Param('id', new ParseUUIDPipe({ version: '4' })) id: string,
  @GetAccount() acct: AccountEntity,
): Promise<ItemEntity> {
  return this.itemService.getItem(id, acct);
}
```

However, when passing a non-UUID it returns this rather unfriendly error message

```
Validation failed (uuid v 4 is expected)
```

Is it possible to customize the returned error message somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's an open PR that will improve that: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/12403

for now you could do something like that:

```js
// ...
export class EnhancedParseUUIDPipe extends ParseUUIDPipe {
  async transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<string> {
    try {
       return await super.transform(value, metadata)
    } catch {
       throw this.exceptionFactory(
        `Validation failed (uuid${
          this.version ? ` v ${this.version}` : ''
        } is expected; given "${value}")`,
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent thank you!  My error is now `Unable to retrieve the data! "${value}" is not a valid ID` - still generic enough to use anywhere, but much friendlier so I can pass it to display directly in the UI.